# run app on android 4.2 with api available only in android 2.3

Tags: android

I have an android library project where I use android 2.3 private API. I have the main android 4.2 project that uses this library project. I need to run this project on android 4.2 device. (android 4.2 doesn't have this api available in android 2.3)
And every time I get the runtime exception:

```
AndroidRuntime(1395): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.pm.IPackageManager.getPackageInfo
```

It's clear why I get it;
but does it possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: You have to adapt your library code to support 4.2 OS too, or turn off that feature if the app running on 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since getPackageInfo is API that added in level 1, it sounds weird. 
See link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String, int)

1. Does Context (Activity, ApplicationContext, etc) was properly set? 
   because getPackageInfo() usually used like below,

   ```
   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo
   ```

   So if **context** or **packageManager** is wrong, getPackageInfo cannot be called.
2. Just Refresh - Clean and do it again. Sometimes it works.
3. Definitely, There exists getPackageInfo() in Android 4.2. (Actually, 2.2 ~ 4.3) It seems that android works fine.